# how to include a sub directory in a excluded directory in gitignore file?

Tags: git, xpages, gitignore

For my XPages application I have set a .gitignore file to exclude the directory where my javascript modules are installed via this definition:

```
ODP/WebContent
```

In that same WebContent folder I have a sub-directory WEB-INF with sub-directories that I want to include for SCM.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgitignore%5D+unignore+subdirectory

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use this:

```
# Ignore ODP/WebContent folder
ODP/WebContent/*
# But include the java files
!ODP/WebContent/WEB-INF/
```